# Problem with the activation of the store with shopware 6.4.20

Tags: php, e-commerce, shopware, shopware6

already weeks I am screening the Internet for a solution to this problem.
I have installed shopware 6.4.20.2 locally and i want to install the shopware store but always falling on this error: "Plugin extraction failed. Error: Detected invalid file/directory SwagExtensionStore/CHANGELOG_de-DE.md in the plugin zip: SwagExtensionStore/.gitignore"

Here is the complete content of my log file:
[2023-06-15T04:30:34.243981+00:00] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Exception\PluginExtractionException: "Plugin extraction failed. Error: Detected invalid file/directory SwagExtensionStore/CHANGELOG_de-DE.md in the plugin zip: SwagExtensionStore/.gitignore" at C:\wamp64\www\newshop\vendor\shopware\core\Framework\Plugin\PluginExtractor.php line 109 {"exception":"[object] (Shopware\Core\Framework\Plugin\Exception\PluginExtractionException(code: 0): Plugin extraction failed. Error: Detected invalid file/directory SwagExtensionStore/CHANGELOG_de-DE.md in the plugin zip: SwagExtensionStore/.gitignore at C:\wamp64\www\newshop\vendor\shopware\core\Framework\Plugin\PluginExtractor.php:109)"} []

Can someone show me how to address this issue?
thanks in advance

I tried reinstalling previous stable versions but still having the same problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with the directory separators of Windows (`\` vs `/`). This should get fixed eventually, as the intend is to offer maximum compatibility, but issues can't be fully ruled out. If you have to stick with `wamp` you could momentarily change [this line](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/aeeadd41f1ac88857e19c399ec6d5b3caa8d6841/src/Core/Framework/Plugin/PluginExtractor.php#L81) to replace `\DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` with `'/'`. Ideally however you should use a proper environment like [Dockware](https://dockware.io/) to be on the safe side.